# como subir imagen con ajax y laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

Quiero guardar una imagen con ajax y laravel pero me sale un error en js, y creo que es porque la imagen no se guarda.

vista

```
<div 
  class="modal fade" 
  id="exampleModal" 
  tabindex="-1" 
  role="dialog" 
  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 b-r"><h3 class="m-t-none m-b">CREAR SLIDER</h3>

            <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>

            {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST','route' => ['inicio.actualizarSler','id'], 'files' => true,'id'=>'form-editarslider']) !!}

            <input type="hidden" id="idslider" name="idslider">
            <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group"><label>Titulo</label> <input 
              type="text" id="tituloEditar" 
              name="tituloEditar" 
              placeholder="Ingrese titulo" class="form-control"></div>
            <div class="form-group"><label>Subtitulo</label> <input 
              type="text" 
              id="subtituloEditar" 
              name="subtituloEditar" 
              placeholder="Ingrese subtitulo" class="form-control"></div>
            <input 
              type="hidden" 
              id="idMenu" 
              name="idMenu" value="{{ $menu->idMenu  }}">

            <div class="form-group"><label>URL</label> <input 
              type="text" 
              id="descripcionEditar" 
              name="descripcionEditar" 
              placeholder="Ingrese enlace" class="form-control"></div>
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::file('rutaImagenSlider',['id'=>'file-rutaImagenSlider']) !!}
                <img name="rutaImagenSlider" 
                  src="" id="rutaImagenSlider" style="width: 50%;"/>
              </div>
            </div>

            {!! Form::close() !!}

            <div>
              <button 
                onclick="guardarSlider();" 
                class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" 
                type="submit"><strong>REGISTRAR</strong></button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS y AJAX

```
<script>
function readURL(input, id) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#' + id).attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
function readURLin(input, id) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#' + id).attr('value', e.target.result);
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#summernote').summernote({
    height: "200px",
  });


  $('#summernote1').summernote({
    height: "200px",
  });

  $('#summernote2').summernote({
    height: "200px",
  });

});

function mostrarEditarSlider(id,titulo,subtitulo,enlace,ruta_imagen) {
  $("#tituloEditar").val(titulo);
  $("#subtituloEditar").val(subtitulo);
  $("#descripcionEditar").val(enlace);
  $("#idslider").val(id);

  document.getElementById("rutaImagenSlider").src = '../../storage/'+ruta_imagen;
  $("#file-rutaImagenSlider").change(function () {
    readURL(this, 'rutaImagenSlider');
    readURLin(this, 'salvacion');
  });

  $("#exampleModal").modal();
}

function guardarSlider() {

  var form =  $("#form-editarslider");

  //datos

  var idslider = $("#idslider").val();
  ///   var token = $("#_token").val();
  var file  = $("#file-rutaImagenSlider").val();
  var titulo = $("#tituloEditar").val();
  var subtitulo = $("#subtituloEditar").val();
  var enlace  =  $("#descripcionEditar").val();
  var idMenu = $("#idMenu").val();
  //  alert(file);return;

  var datos = {
    'titulo' :titulo,
    'file' : file,
    'idslider' : idslider,
    'subtitulo' : subtitulo,
    'enlace' : enlace,
    'idMenu' : idMenu
  };
  var urles = form.attr('action').replace('id',$("#idslider").val());
  var formdata = form.serialize();

  // console.log(datos);return;
  $.post({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: urles,
    data:datos,
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (res) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  })
}

</script>
```

CONTROLADOR

```
public function actualizarSler(Request $request)
{
  $slider = Detalle_imagen::find($request->cod);
  $slider->titulo = $request->titulo;
  $slider->subtitulo = $request->subtitulo;
  $slider->enlace = $request->enlace;

  if (isset($request->file)) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $slider->rutaImagen =  $file->getClientOriginalName();
    \Storage::disk('local')->put( $slider->rutaImagen,  \File::get($file));
  } else {
    $res="chau";
  }

  $slider->save();

  //$res="chau";
  return response()->json($slider->rutaImagen);
}
```

Comment: Cual es el Error que te sale?

Comment: **http://localhost/cisne2/public/Inicio/actualizarSler/2 500 (Internal Server Error)**

Comment: pero cuando le quito la parte donde guarda la imagen ahi si me corre normal, claro sin guardar la imagen, otra cosa es que com puedes ver mando el valor del input y lo que recibo es c/path/nombredelaimage y creo q eso esta mal y por eso no guardda

Comment: Usa el inspector de google chrome, y en la pestaña de network veras el cargue de los archivos y te debe salir la ruta con el error 500 al darle clic, le das a la pestaña preview y podras ver el error que te envía laravel. Tambien puedes ver el objeto que te da en la consola, para ver mas claramente cual es el error.